# Convert array to object, based on even/odd index

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I am trying to convert an array to an object based on whether the index of array is odd or even.

For example,,

Input:
  `["name", "Tom", "age", 20]`

output:`{ "name": "tom","age": 20 }`

It can be implemented using basic functions of JavaScript such as `forEach`, `map`, and `filter`. But I want more simple code.

So I checked docs of underscore.js, but I couldn't find a good way.
Is there any way to solve this simply?

Comment: Please let me know if there are any modules that can solve this problem simply. (similar to underscore.js)

Answer (score 5):

Interesting question, my two cents:

Simple and performant for loop:

```
const simpleArray = ["name", "Tom", "age", 20];

// Modifying the Array object
Array.prototype.toObject = function() {
    let r = {};

    for(let i = 0; i < this.length; i += 2) {
        let key = this[i], value = this[i + 1];
        r[key] = value;
    }

    return r;
}

// Or as a function
const toObject = arr => {
    let r = {};

    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
        let key = arr[i], value = arr[i + 1];
        r[key] = value;
    }

    return r;
}

const simpleObjectOne = simpleArray.toObject(); // First method
const simpleObjectTwo = toObject(simpleArray); // Second method
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and a check for the index, if uneven, then assign the element to the key from the last item.

```js
var array =  ["name", "Tom", "age", 20],
    object = {};

array.forEach(function (a, i, aa) {
    if (i & 1) {
        object[aa[i - 1]] = a;
    }
});

console.log(object);
```

The same with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
var array =  ["name", "Tom", "age", 20],
    object = array.reduce(function (r, a, i, aa) {
        if (i & 1) {
            r[aa[i - 1]] = a;
        }
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(object);
```

Comment: Sure, but he said he doesn't want to use `forEach` etc.

Comment: and op says, "*But I want more simple code.*", which is questionable.

Comment: Yes, I wondered if there was a new interesting simple way. Your answer was helpful to me...!! XD

Comment: Can I ask you something? In the case of forEach, Is `array` equal to `aa`? If then, why does callback function of forEach use `aa` as a parameter?

Comment: it is safer than hard coded reference to an array outside. this style make the callback reusable for other arrays as well.

Comment: @NinaScholz can you please explain how the `(i & 1)` works? and why have you used it like this?

Comment: @cowCrazy, what you see, is a [bitwise AND `&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_AND). any operand is converted to an integer value (which is given) and the operation perfomes an AND which returns a new number, in this case, the given numer is a positive 32 bit integer value from the index and with AND, it returns only the last bit.

Comment: @cowCrazy, ... this is `1` if the number is odd, otherwise zero, which is a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)/[falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value, pefect for the condition.

Answer (score 2):

Underscore solution:

```
output = _.object(..._.partition(input, (_, i) => !(i % 2)))
```

`_.partition` will partition the array into `[['name', 'age'], ["tom", "20"]]`. In other words, it returns an array containing two subarrays--in this case, one array of keys and one array of values. `_.object` takes an array of keys and an array of values as parameters, so we use `...` to pass the subarrays in the value returned by `_.partition` to it as two parameters.

If you're into very functional, semantic code:

```
const even = i => !(i % 2);
const index = fn => (_, i) => fn(i);

output = _.object(..._.partition(input, index(even)))
```

Recursive solution:

```
function arrayToObject([prop, value, ...rest], result = {}) {
  return prop ? arrayToObject(rest, Object.assign(result, {[prop]: value})) : result;
}
```

Iterative solution:

```
function arrayToObject(arr) {
  const result = {};
  while (arr.length) result[arr.shift()] = arr.shift();
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var input = ["name", "Tom", "age", 20] ;
var output = {}
input.forEach((x, i, arr) => {
  if (i % 2 === 0) output[x] = arr[i+1];
});
console.log(output); //{ name: 'Tom', age: 20 }
```

Comment: Sorry but I'm a beginner in Javascript .. TT .. Is `arr` equal to `input`? If then, why does callback function of forEach use `arr` as a parameter?

Comment: Yes, the callback function function takes 3 arguments : 
    the element value, 
    the element index, 
    and the array being traversed.

Comment: Isn't the condition `i < input.length - 1` redundant?

Comment: Yes of course since I target even index in an even length array. I've just remove this irelevant condition. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may also use reduce

```js
var arr = ["name", "Tom", "age", 20],
    obj = arr.reduce((p,c,i,a) => (i%2 ? p[a[i-1]] = c : p[c],p),{});
console.log(obj);
```

for this operation as follows;

Comment: What is the meaning/effect of the `p[c]` after the colon?

Answer (score 0):

A simple for loop

```
var arr = ["name", "Tom", "age", 20, "address"];
var obj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=2){
    //First iteration: assign obj["name"] to "Tom"
    //Second iteration: assign obj["age"] to 20
    //Third iteration: assign obj["address"] to "" because arr[5] does not exist
    obj[arr[i]] = arr[i+1] || "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = ["name", "Tom", "age", 20, "address", "London"];

function parseParams([k, v, ...rest]) {
  return k ? { [k]: v, ...parseParams(rest) } : {};
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(parseParams(arr), null, 3));

// e.g. node js to get arguments that way
// parseParams(process.argv.slice(2));
```